# Matlab: Removing white cells from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to only remove white blood cells and keep red blood cells from the image below. What is the best way to do this in Matlab?
[image: blood cells]

```
format longg;
format compact;
fontSize = 16;
rgbImage = imread('E:\GP_Final\DS\CL_13-09_image2.jpg');
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
% imshow(rgbImage, []);

% title('Original Color Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);
% figure(2),imshow(hsv);
% Display the color channels.
hueImage = hsv(:, :, 1);
saturationImage = hsv(:, :, 2);
valueImage = hsv(:, :, 3);
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(hueImage, []);
title('Hue Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize);
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(saturationImage, []); 
title('Saturation Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize);
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(valueImage, [])
title('Value Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize);
[pixelCounts values] = hist(hueImage, 500);
 figure;
 bar(values, pixelCounts);
title('Histogram of Hue Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize);
redPixels = hueImage > 0.3 & hueImage >0.8 & valueImage <= 0.9;
% figure(10);
% imshow(redPixels);
% title('Map of red Pixels', 'FontSize', fontSize);
saturationImage(redPixels) = saturationImage(redPixels) *3.5;
% figure(7),imshow(saturationImage);
% title('New Saturation Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize);

% Combine back to form new hsv image
hsvImage = cat(3, hueImage, saturationImage, valueImage);
% Convert back to RGB color space.
rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);
figure(8), imshow(rgbImage);
title('RGB Image with Enhanced red', 'FontSize', fontSize);

se1 = strel('disk',1);
 erodedBW = imerode(redPixels,se1);
se2 = strel('disk',2);
 dilatedBW2 = imdilate(erodedBW,se2);
se3 = strel('disk',1);
 openedBW = imopen(dilatedBW2,se3);

 filledBW=imfill(openedBW,'holes');
 figure(3), imshow(filledBW);title('after fill holes  ');


bw3=bwareaopen(filledBW,80);
    figure(5), imshow(bw3);title('after remove small objects ');
```

that is i did but it not work for all images, there is any way to solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

You wish to remove out the deep purple cell in the middle of the image.  It's a very simple task in looking at the colour distribution in the [HSV colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).  I wouldn't look at the hue in this case because the colour distribution of the image will most likely have similar hues.  The saturation is what I would aim for.

Let's read in the image from StackOverflow, convert the image to HSV and look at the saturation component:

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQUKj.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(im2double(im));
imshow(hsv(:,:,2))
```

We get this image:

[image]

You can clearly see that the "red" blood cell has a higher saturation than the background, and so we can do some simple thresholding.  A saturation of 0.4 seems to work for me:

```
mask = hsv(:,:,2) > 0.4;
imshow(mask);
```

We get this:

[image]

There are some spurious pixels, so we can remove this with a [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) operation.  Any pixels whose areas are below 300 I remove:

```
mask_remove = bwareaopen(mask, 300);
imshow(mask_remove);
```

We get this:

[image]

Now, there are holes in this remaining cell.  We can remedy this by filling these holes using [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) and selecting the `holes` option:

```
mask_fill = imfill(mask_remove, 'holes');
imshow(mask_fill);
```

We get this:

[image]

I'm going to dilate this mask slightly to make sure we get rid of the rest of the purple surroundings:

```
se = strel('square', 7);
mask_final = imdilate(mask_fill, se);
```

The last thing to do is to use this mask and mask the original image, then produce a final image with the white blood cell remove.  Simply invert the mask and multiply this with the original image, then fill in the missing information with white:

```
mask_final = repmat(mask_final, [1 1 3]);
out = im .* uint8(~mask_final);
out(mask_final) = 255;
imshow(out);
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: sorry , but the white blood cell not the background its the strange color in the middle of image which have a different color i marked in this link https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/11351304_670217563112162_6449690187812091844_n.jpg?oh=55c18366748434df0d5a6e3885ba38d0&oe=56293B2C&__gda__=1444965642_f3e46cf56b64d0fab2e7809a511811a6

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works well in this image only , but for sorry i have some images and i want to input any images and extract only red cells to enter into another stages of processing as counting. 
theirs images . 
i want a code for any blood image.
http://imgur.com/a/deJra

Comment: If you'd like to continue this further and adapt this for any image of this type, you can hire me as a Codementor. Considering that you didn't try anything and made no effort, this is more than enough to get you started. If you don't want to hire me, I'm going to leave this task for you to figure it out. This is more than enough to get your started. Good luck!

Comment: okay i have tried and do this but it still not working for all images 
rgbImage = imread('image2.jpg');
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);hueImage = hsv(:, :, 1);
saturationImage = hsv(:, :, 2);
valueImage = hsv(:, :, 3);
[pixelCounts values] = hist(hueImage, 500);
 figure; bar(values, pixelCounts);
title('Histogram of Hue Channel');
redPixels = hueImage > 0.3 & hueImage >0.8 & valueImage <= 0.9;
saturationImage(redPixels) = saturationImage(redPixels) *3.5;
hsvImage = cat(3, hueImage, saturationImage, valueImage);

rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);

Comment: Update your post with your code. It's very ugly to read code in a comments block that is more than a couple of lines long.

Comment: then i do morphological operation to the enhanced red object i get  

se1 = strel('disk',1);
 erodedBW = imerode(redPixels,se1);
se2 = strel('disk',2);
 dilatedBW2 = imdilate(erodedBW,se2);
 openedBW = imopen(dilatedBW2,se1);
 filledBW=imfill(openedBW,'holes');
bw3=bwareaopen(filledBW,80);
figure(5), imshow(bw3);title('after remove small objects ');

Comment: sorry for Disturbance , can you help me ?

Comment: @SamiRaSaǮed - Not right now unfortunately.  Perhaps in a few hours.  I'm spending time with family.

Answer (score -2):

You can import the image by dragging it into the workspace or clicking the 'import' button in Matlab. This will give you a width x height x 3 matrix which contains the RGB values per pixel. By thresholding the red, green a blue values, you can select which pixels to edit. Using `imview()` and `imsave()`, you can view and store the result.

To edit multiple images, you can use (replace png with the extension you have):

```
fileNames = [cellstr('name1'), cellstr('name2')]; % The images to process without extension.
for i = 1:length(fileNames)
  img = imread([char(fileNames(i)), '.png']);
  % Process the image here.
  % ...
  imwrite([char(fileNames(i)), '-edited.png'], 'png');
end
```

Comment: i have more than one image , i don't want to do it manually i want to input the image and the output will enter in another processing steps and counting , can you help me ?

Comment: I've added code that allows you to autoload and save multiple images.

Comment: i don't want to save them , i want to extract only red blood cells and count them